# Compound Select to Use in Manipulate

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, filtering

I've imported a table using the following:

```
dataset = Dataset[SemanticImport["C:/Downloads/test.xlsx"]]
```

Then I am using Manipulate as follows:

```
Manipulate[ dataset [Select [ #C1 > n1 & ]], {n1, 1, 100}]
```

I would like to concurrently do likewise for a second column, C2.  So there would be two sliders.  That would require putting in an "AND", and basically a repeat of the Select, except this time using C2 and n2.

Here are the first few lines of the dataset:

```
X   C1  C2
_22704_1    53  97
_21801_0    28  47
_21405_0    2   25
_21506_0    58  49
_21704_1    93  65
_21504_0    64  46
_21101_0    9   6
_21301_0    72  90
_23003_0    14  20
```

Can someone please tell me how to write the compound command?  Hopefully extensible for far more than just two columns.

Thanks,
Nicholas Kormanik

---

Thought the following looked logical and would work.  But, no.  Error message: Too few arguments given. (??)

```
Manipulate[
dataset[
Select[
And[
#C1 > n1 &, {n1, 1, 100}, 
#C2 > n2 &, {n2, 1, 100}
]]]]
```

@Kuba, your suggestion above didn't work.  Please offer another?  Manipulate is **essential** to this problem, by the way.

Comment: To where are you referring, @Kuba?  I haven't been able to find any examples of such.  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html

Comment: `Mod[#, 3] == 1 && Mod[#, 5] == 1 &` - isn't this a compound condition?

Comment: Not familiar with that one.  Care to show with above coding I provided?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tr = "X   C1  C2
 _22704_1    53  97
 _21801_0    28  47
 _21405_0    2   25
 _21506_0    58  49
 _21704_1    93  65
 _21504_0    64  46
 _21101_0    9   6
 _21301_0    72  90
 _23003_0    14  20"
```

You say my suggestion didn't work but I don't see you using it. Moreover, where did you get a tip to use `, {n1, 1, 100}` inside select. Please focus on documentation of all related symbols, like `Select`, `And`, `Manipulate`.

```
dataset =  Dataset@(
   Function[triplet,  AssociationThread[# -> triplet]] /@ {##2}
) & @@  ImportString[tr, "Table"] 


Manipulate[
 dataset[Select[And[#C1 > n1, #C2 > n2] &]], 
 {n1, 1, 100}, 
 {n2, 1, 100}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Great job, @Kuba.  I've been thoroughly frustrated all day trying different arrangements.

Comment: The following arrangement works as well: Manipulate[
 Select[dataset, #C1 > n1 && #C2 > n2 &], {n1, 1, 100}, {n2, 1, 100}]

Comment: Just curious, @Kuba, you chose to use a much longer more complex Import method than SemanticImport.  Is there any reason to not use SemanticImport to quickly grab a simple Excel spreadsheet?  As the actual spreadsheets I'm dealing with have many columns and rows, not sure I could configure what you've done for the cases at hand.  Guidance appreciated.